# Why I cannot run tests on play 2?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a simple Email class like (I am using [Emailer](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer) plugin):

```
public class Email {

public static boolean sendEmail(final String to, final String body, final String subject) {

    MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.addRecipient(to);

    try {
        mail.send(body);
        Logger.info(String.format("Sucessfully sent an email to %s", to));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.info(String.format("An error occured when trying to send email to %s: %s", to, e.getStackTrace()));
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

and I tried to test this using a test class:

```
public class EmailTest {

@Test
public void sendEmail() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            boolean status = Email.sendEmail("my_email", "hello", "subject demo");
            assertThat(status).equals("true");
        }
    });
}
```

}

I run: `play test` but I receive:

```
    [info] EmailTest
[error] Test EmailTest.sendEmail failed: null
[error]     at utils.Email.sendEmail(Email.java:12)
[error]     at EmailTest$1.run(EmailTest.java:15)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:294)
[error]     at EmailTest.sendEmail(EmailTest.java:13)
[error]     ...
[info] x EmailTest.sendEmail
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test EmailTest
[info] Finished in 11.073 seconds
[info] 1 tests, 1 failures, 0 errors
[error] Failed: : Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? It does not throw an exception more clear to find out the cause of failig...

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs not because of test workflow but because I forgot to add this:

`1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin`

to play.plugins.